# Как вызвать терминал в проекте на codesandbox.io?

Tags: консоль, ide, codesandbox

В [некоторых проектах](https://codesandbox.io/s/ky5lj09jv) он активирован по умолчанию, а в [других](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new) - нет.

Как его активировать вручную?

[image: Примеры наличия и отсутствия терминалов в проектах на codesandbox.io]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого надо сменить Окружение (*Environment*).

[[image: Поле, в котором указано текущее Окружение]

Они неявным образом подразделяются на серверные и интерфейсные,
и терминал доступен только для серверных:

[image: Две группы шаблонов проектов]

Судя по всему, переключать codesandbox-проект с "интерфейсного" на "серверный" невозможно, и чтобы активировать терминал, нужно создать новый, "серверный" проект.